# /usr/bin/ld: warning: libavcodec.so.53, needed by xxx not found

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, makefile, libavcodec

I am trying to compile a given source code with makefile, but the problem I am facing is the fact that it uses libavcodec.so.53. The version installed is 54, the libavutil and libavformat versions are also different from the Linux version. I can't change the version of them in Linux because I don't have root access. So I will use a local folder where opencv, libavutil.so, libavformat.so and libavcodec.so.53 are.

I put this folder name into the makefile.config as it follows:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /home/me/lib

LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/local /home/me/lib
```

But when I compile it I have the following errors:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: warning: libavcodec.so.53, needed by 
 /home/anselmo/lib/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -
 rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavformat.so.53, needed by   
/home/me/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavutil.so.51, needed by  
/home/me/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or  rpath-link)

/home/anselmo/lib/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to 
`avcodec_flush_buffers@LIBAVCODEC_53'
/home/me/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to  
`av_freep@LIBAVUTIL_51'
/home/me/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to        
`av_read_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_53'
```

libavutil.so.51, libavformat.so.53 and libavcodec.so.53 are in /home/me/lib as indicated in the makefile. How to show linux how to use them instead of the ones installed in the machine? again, I cannot be root.

Comment: If you put the `/home/me/lib` paths first, does it work then? It looks to me as though the linker is searching the wrong places first.

Comment: Building is giving you that error? Or running the code is? What **exact** command is generating those errors?

Comment: make all command is giving the error